# Ms Lightswitch - add dynamic (from code behind) items choice list

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Microsoft LightSwitch framework, need to add dynamic items in choice list. So far I found different posts saying that choice list is only for static items and you have to use a separate table if you need to populate it in non-static means.

In my case, table will also not be a good option, I want to add items manually from C# code. Actually I need to populate years combobox, for this I need to add last 3 years, current year, and one next year. This I could not achieve through static data or TABLE will also be not a good idea.

Comment: Desktop or HTML client?

Comment: Silverlight client, web.

Answer (score 0):

just create a lookup table and add a relationship and LS will do the rest

You can always dynamically populate the new table

Although you won't be able to delete records that have children

Comment: And on year changed, each time I need to delete rows from table and populate with new rows. Also I have to do the same with Months list. As mentioned in question, this trick is not a good idea. There should be some proper mechanism to populate custom items in Choice List. I hope microsoft will provide in future if currently we don't have.

Comment: I doubt Microsoft will make any more changes to LightSwitch going forward as they have stopped working on it for the last 8 months or so

Comment: Oh. So means there is no hope left :) I think then I have to look for some other work around if possible, otherwise I have to come back to the same 'table' idea.

Comment: If they do start working on it again I guess they would announce it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/